# xpath got wrong html attribute

Tags: php, curl, xpath

So, I have this PHP scraper code and HTML below that I want to scrape using Xpath. 
When I try to scrape every `@href`, it shows outerHTML `<a href="\&quot;javascript:cal_action(14,">14</a>`, when it is supposes to be `<a href="\&quot;javascript:cal_action(14, 2, 2014)\&quot;">14</a>`
The `@href` is cut in half where the space are. What causes this?

```
$content = $xpath->query('//a');

    foreach($content as $c){
        var_dump(htmlspecialchars($c->C14N())); echo '<br>';
    }
```

The one above is the CURL code.
Here is the HTML.

```
    <div class="outercalendar" id="maincalendar821"><table class="calendarHeader">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="AjxGetMainCalendarMonth('2', '2015', '821')" value="<"></td>
    <td class="calendarHeader" colspan="5">March 2015</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="AjxGetMainCalendarMonth('4', '2015', '821')" value=">"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <table class="calendar">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td class="calendarDay">S</td>
    <td class="calendarDay">M</td>
    <td class="calendarDay">T</td>
    <td class="calendarDay">W</td>
    <td class="calendarDay">T</td>
    <td class="calendarDay">F</td>
    <td class="calendarDay">S</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(1, 3, 2015)">1</a></td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(7, 3, 2015)">7</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(8, 3, 2015)">8</a></td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(14, 3, 2015)">14</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(15, 3, 2015)">15</a></td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(21, 3, 2015)">21</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(22, 3, 2015)">22</a></td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(28, 3, 2015)">28</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="calendar"><a href="javascript:cal_action(29, 3, 2015)">29</a></td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="calendar">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: Actually, I've written the code above...
I am sorry, I didn't write clear enough, I already edit it

Here it is again to make sure

    $content = $xpath->query('//a');
    
        foreach($content as $c){
            var_dump(htmlspecialchars($c->C14N())); echo '<br>';
        }

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in the structure of the info stored in the tag.

I would suggest starting with a more detailed xpath:

`//a/@href`

so your initial code would be:

```
$content = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
```

Comment: what happen if you directly print the values in $content ?

Comment: I got this `\&quot;javascript:cal_action(14,`